# Where to find the amount of mulch I have?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

How can I tell how much mulch I have?  When I go to plant a berry it asks me if I want to use a mulch, but I'm not sure how to tell what I currently have.  I've looked in the bags and I don't see it listed in any of the categories.

The problem is, I want to add mulch to all spots but I need to know how much I have to make in the composters.

Comment: Mulch is in your backpack, I'm pretty sure.  Problem is finding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mulch is stored in the "Items" pocket of the inventory, along with other miscellaneous things like Poké Balls and held items.  If you've sorted the pocket by type, it appears after Mega Stones, field items (repels, escape rope, honey), valuable items (nugget, pearl, etc.), & Prism Scales and before fossils, evolutionary stones, & Poké Balls.